# Using Java classes from another APK

Tags: android

Because of license considerations, I would like to distribute my Android app, as 2 separated APKs. The first APK would contain the open source library, and the second will contain prorietary code. Is it technically possible to have in the second APK direct calls to the classes in the first APK, without the usage of AIDL ?

Comment: Your first APK could have a service that the second APK accesses through AIDL, if that is what you are asking. This requires users to install both apps, so you need to deal with the case where the user installed one but not the other. Also, both APKs should have intrinsic standalone value, if you are distributing them through the Play Store or other public channels. Otherwise, you are likely to get poor reviews from users who get frustrated with the "please install the other app" step.

Comment: Actually, my point was exactely how to avoid using AIDL... Is it possible to have direct calls, inheritance, etc ?

Comment: Your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48990626/1) specifically stated "with the usage of AIDL".

Comment: Indeed... that was a mistake in my description, and I wrote exactely the inverse what I wanted to ask :( For now, I'm exploring how I can load dynamically a dex file, that is included in another apk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to do it as the following :

1. I created a new module, that builds a library. To this module, I have added 2 gradle tasks, that build first a .jar, then build a .dex

```html
task makeJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('build/outputs/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', 'my.jar')
}
task makeDex(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "${projectDir}"
    commandLine android.sdkDirectory.path + '/build-tools/27.0.3/dx.bat', '--dex', '--output=build/outputs/my.dex.jar', 'build/outputs/my.jar'
}
```

2. I created a new app, with a AIDL service that allows downloading the content of the file `my.dex.jar`
3. In my original app, I download the my.dex.jar file, and load the dex in memory. In my original, I use a dependecy on the file my.jar, and I specify that it should not be inserted in the APK :

```html
dependencies {
   provided files('../my_library/build/outputs/my.jar')
}
```